# GPG - Can't Find File Specified Error Even Though File is There

Tags: powershell, filter, gnupg

I have a PowerShell script where I'm assigning two files to a variable, using that variable in the Get-ChildItem cmdlet with the -Include parameters. I assign the result of Get-ChildItem to a variable and then write the contents of the variable to the logs. The files are clearly in the list, but when I use GPG to encrypt, it's saying the file cannot be found.

File filter variable:
`$FileFilter = 'status_*.csv','financial_transactions_*.csv'`

Writing getting the files and writing the result out:

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include $FileFilter -Recurse
Write-Host $allfiles
```

Result in the logs:

```
E:\temp\reports\2022\07\01\financial_transactions_20220701_000.CSV 
E:\temp\reports\2022\07\01\status_20220701_000.CSV 
E:\temp\reports\2022\07\02\status_20220702_000.CSV
```

Full code to encrypt the file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include $FileFilter -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Verbose {
$FileFullPath = $_.FullName
        
Write-Host "Encrypting" $FileFullPath
        
$NewEncryptFile = $_.FullName + '.PGP'
Write-Host "New file name is "$NewEncryptFile"."
        
Write-Host "In test. Using GnuPG."
Write-Host $NewEncryptFile
Write-Host $FileFullPath
Start-Process -filepath $GPGExePath -RedirectStandardError "E:\Scripts\error.txt" -Wait -ArgumentList "--batch --yes --output $NewEncryptFile --encrypt --recipient $GPGUser $FileFullPath"
}
```

I write out the path to the CSV file and the path where the encrypted file needs to go, which is the same location. I have physically gone to the location of the CSV files and it is there., I get the error "Error: This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."

When I assign one file to the $FileFilter variable, the GPG code works.

Comment: Can we see the full code? It's like you need to move your call to start the encryption `start-process` to a different part of the loop. At whatever point you are searching for the output file, the loop cannot find the file, possibly because it's in the same loop.

Comment: Also, you are changing your file names to `file.csv.pgp` is this intentional?

Comment: also, also, you never actually `move-item` or `rename-item` which renames the file. is this elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Is your E:\ drive local, or is it a mapped/PSDrive?  Have you put in a breakpoint to confirm that $_.FullName is what you expect it to be?